# Error: Class has no member named 'ThisW'; did you mean 'This'? But the code doesn't say 'ThisW' it already says 'This'

Tags: c++

**Fixed by renaming CreateFile to MakeFile**

I am inexperienced with c++ and am in the middle of combining a GUI and an existing project so there may be a lot of issues, but the main issue I am unable to solve right now is this 'no member' error.

The error is:

```
'class FileHandler' has no member named 'CreateFileW'; did you mean 'CreateFile'?

main.cpp:51:32: error: no member named 'CreateFileW' in 'FileHandler'

fileapi.h:31:20: note: expanded from macro 'CreateFile'

_mingw_unicode.h:12:32: note: expanded from macro '__MINGW_NAME_AW'

2:1: note: expanded from here
```

However, the code itself doesn't say CreateFileW so where is the W coming from?

**Main.cpp** - up to the error

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit
#include <cstdio>  // File


#include "file_handler.h"
#include "data_store.h"
#include "cpl_data_store.h"
#include "opl_data_store.h"
#include "data_processor.h"
#include "view.h"
#include "file.h"
#include "screen.h"
#include "structs.h"
#include "dialog.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Dialog w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();

    // create filehandler object that will handle file operations
    FileHandler fh;

    // get the filename given by the user using command line arguments
    std::string filename = "Test";  //fh.GetFilename(argc, argv);

    // open file for reading
    FILE * ballot_file = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");

    // file validation, check file exist, if not output error message and exit program
    if (ballot_file == NULL) {
        std::cout << "Error. File cannot be opened." << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // read from file, returns a vector with all the data, so size of vector should = number of lines
    // possible bug here if number of lines in file is > vector max size
    std::vector<std::string> file_info = fh.ReadFromFile(ballot_file);

    // done reading, close ballot file
    fclose(ballot_file);

    // create audit file
    File audit_file("audit.txt", "textfile");
    FILE * audit_file_ptr = fh.CreateFile(audit_file.GetName());

    // create media file
    File media_file("media.txt", "textfile");
    FILE * media_file_ptr = fh.CreateFile(media_file.GetName());
```

**file_handler.cc**

```
/**
 * @file file_handler.cc
 *
 * @copyright 2019 Team32, All rights reserved.
 */
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>  // File
#include <vector>

#include "file_handler.h"

std::string FileHandler::GetFilename(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    std::string filename;

    if (argc == 2) {
        filename = argv[1];
    } else if (argc == 1) {  // no input file given
        // output error message
        std::cout << "Error. Please provide a filename." << std::endl;
        // get filename
        std::cout << "Enter a filename: ";
        std::cin >> filename;
    } else {  // more than 2 arguments given
        // output error message
        std::cout << "Error. " << argc << " arguments given. 2 arguments expected." << std::endl;
        // get filename
        std::cout << "Enter a filename: ";
        std::cin >> filename;
    }

    return filename;
}

std::vector<std::string> FileHandler::ReadFromFile(FILE * file_pointer) {
    std::vector<std::string> file_info;  // stores lines read in

    char str[500];  // hold the line read in

    while (fscanf(file_pointer, "%s", str) != EOF) {
         file_info.push_back(str);
    }

    return file_info;
}

FILE * FileHandler::CreateFile(std::string filename) {
     return fopen(filename.c_str(), "w+");
}

void FileHandler::WriteToFile(FILE *file_pointer, std::string str) {
    std::string output = str + "\n";
    fprintf (file_pointer, output.c_str());
}
```

**file_handler.h**

```
/**
 * @file file_handler.h
 *
 * @copyright 2019 Team32, All rights reserved.
 */
#ifndef SRC_FILE_HANDLER_H_
#define SRC_FILE_HANDLER_H_

/*******************************************************************************
 * Includes
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>  // File
#include <vector>

/*******************************************************************************
 * Class Definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
/**
* @brief Class that store all the election data read in from a file.
*/
class FileHandler {
    public:
        /**
        * @brief Gets the name of the user given file from the terminal.
        *
        * @param[in] int number of arguments given from the command line
        * @param[in] char * an array that contains arguments from the command line
        *
        * @return the input filename
        */
        std::string GetFilename(int argc, char const *argv[]);
        /**
        * @brief Read from a file
        *
        * @param[in] File * pointer to a file that we want to read from
        *
        * @return a vector with each element being a line read in from a file
        */
        std::vector<std::string> ReadFromFile(FILE * file_pointer);
        /**
        * @brief Creates a new file
        *
        * @param[in] std::string name of file that should be created
        *
        * @return File * to the file created
        */
        FILE * CreateFile(std::string filename);
        /**
        * @brief Write a string to a file
        *
        * @param[in] File * pointer to a file that should be written in
        * @param[in] std::string string to be written into the file
        */
        void WriteToFile(FILE *file_pointer, std::string str);
};
#endif  // SRC_FILE_HANDLER_H_
```

Comment: That worked! Renamed to MakeFile and it immediately fixed the issue. Tas you are the best!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you're including some Windows libraries, where [`CreateFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) is a `#define` which points to a different function, namely `CreateFileW`. I think the easiest solution is to just rename *your* function to just `Create` or something, or `MakeFile` or something else. I think you'll find by renaming it it will probably solve your issue.

A very similar issue exists where Windows has a `#define` called `min` which screws up uses of `std::min`